# Change css properties, like color and background, for lines starting with "#" within <pre>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a minimal code syntax highlighting rule to a web page by only changing the color of comments - lines starting with "#" symbol within the `<pre><code>` tags.

To my surprise I could not find information about this by searching on StackOverflow. However projects such as [ft-syntax-highlight](https://github.com/soulshined/ft-syntax-highlight) make me assume this to be possible.

Is it possible to adjust the color of lines starting with "#" in the following code block using only css?:

```
<pre><code>
# function to do something
do_something_here(x1, x2);
</code></pre>
```

And if so - how?

Comment: you can't manipulate text with css... in this case you should have a js script that check your text and wrap the text between a "#" and a "\n" in a span with the color you want

Comment: Based on my understanding of the readme in the project you linked, it relies on tagging parts of the code with expected classes, which can't be done with CSS alone.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia & @Phix thank you for the comments. That would explain why I wasn't able to find any information about this, and that `ft-syntax-highlight` confused things further. If you think the question still deserves an answer (stating that this is not possible) - would be glad to accept.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not what you're looking for but a minimal workaround would be using CSS's `content` and `:before`

[View in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfgh3opu/)

```css
[comment]:before {
  content: "# " attr(comment);
  color: red;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 45vw;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code comment="function to do something here line function to do something here line function to do something here line">
do_something_here(x1, x2);
</code>

<code comment="you can use `missing()` to test whether or not the argument y was supplied">
fooBar <- function(x,y){
  if(missing(y)) {
      x
  } else {
      x + y
  }
}
</code>
</pre>
```

Note: use`data-comment` instead of `comment` for better html semantics

Comment: Interesting approach, upvoted, but sadly yes - this is not really what I was looking for.